# Nextjs what is " .next/BUILD_ID" and why is it missing? And why is --trace-warnings not working?

Tags: next.js

So I built a super simple NEXTjs app to start playing around with it a 2weeks ago. Worked fine. Came back to it today and I get this error message...

```
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.19
$ next start
(node:40361) ExperimentalWarning: stream/web is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
- ready started server on [::]:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/unclefonso/Projects/typescript-stuff/basic-site/.next/BUILD_ID'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/home/unclefonso/Projects/typescript-stuff/basic-site/.next/BUILD_ID'
}
Done in 0.51s.
```

Adding "--trace-warnings" to my package.json start scripts does nothing

```
{
  "name": "basic-site",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev --trace-warnings",  <-------DOES NOT WORK
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start --trace-warnings", <-----ALSO, DOES NOT WORK
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.5.0",
    "@types/react": "18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "eslint": "8.47.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.16",
    "next": "13.4.16",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  }
}
```

The error message looks like so...

```
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.19
$ next start --trace-warnings
(node:41733) ExperimentalWarning: stream/web is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Unknown or unexpected option: --trace-warnings
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Any ideas as to...

1. what .next/BUILD_ID
2. why --trace-warnings will not work?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly is `BUILD_ID` but it happens when you run the application without building it first.
If you want to run it in a dev env use run `yarn run dev`. If you want to build and run, use `yarn run build` and then `yarn start`.

Hope this helped :)

Comment: That's doesn't seem to be right because I got the same error after building my Nextjs application before running ```yarn start```.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the specifics of this error, but two things you could try are: 1) deleting `.next` and rebuilding the application, or 2) creating a `generateBuildId` function inside your next config that returns something like `Date.now().toString()`

Answer (score 0):

BUIL_ID is a file with no extension holding a unique identifier key that Next uses to identify which version of your application is being served, [learn more here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/generateBuildId).

I was having the same issue on a project I exported as static HTML/CSS/JS through the config `output: 'export'` of next.config.js. It seems like a BUILD_ID is not generated for such output, so I removed the config to allow default behaviour and everything worked fine. I could then run `next start` flawlessly.